# What does "Emulator: FramebufferData::restore: warning: a texture is deleted without unbinding FBO" mean and how do I resolve this?

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm simply trying to run my application, and everytime I run it, it gives me this message and it stops running the apps. The AVD stays open and I can see a typical android home screen, but my app simply doesn't run. The Gradle build completes and builds properly, but my app still won't open.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
String [] states = {"Alabama","Alaska","Arizona","Arkansas", "the rest of the US states"};

String storage = "";
Double stormCount = 0.0;
int yearChoice;
double xval = yearChoice - 1950;

Spinner stateSpinner;
EditText yearInput;
TextView networkResults;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    stateSpinner = findViewById(R.id.stateSpinner);
    ArrayAdapter <String> adapter;
    yearInput = findViewById(R.id.yearInput);
    networkResults = findViewById(R.id.networkResults);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,states);
    stateSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    yearChoice = Integer.valueOf(yearInput.getText().toString());

    stateSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

            if(position == 0) {
                stormCount = 14.5160471387124 * Math.pow(Math.E, .0742980947989195 * xval);
                storage = "The amount of storms in "+states[position]+" in "+yearChoice+" is "+Math.floor(stormCount)+". This reading is about 70% accurate.";
            }

            if(position == 1) {
                storage = ("Sorry, data from your region currently has too low an accuracy rate to be used");
            }

            if(position == 2) {
                stormCount = (.000000293212037634147 * Math.pow(xval, 6)) - (.0000642428907817738 * Math.pow(xval, 5)) + (.00526808502644371 * Math.pow(xval, 4))
                        - (.195157071357244 * Math.pow(xval, 3)) + (3.27415865786315 * Math.pow(xval, 2)) - (20.6557307408656 * xval) + 35.8205191551242;
                storage = ("The amount of storms in "+states[position]+" in "+yearChoice+" is "+Math.floor(stormCount)+". This reading is about 70% accurate.");
            }
```

----A BUNCH MORE IF STATEMENTS FOR EACH ELEMENT IN THE ARRAY----

```
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });

}

public void submitButtonClicked(View v) {
    networkResults.setText(storage);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a specific emulator issue and not your app. Try a clean start of your virtual device: AVD Device Manager, select your emulator, hit Actions > Wipe Data and start over. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with the Pixel 2XL API 29 Emulator and solved it by going to tools>AVD Manager>Right Click AVD > Wipe Data + Cold Boot.

Haven't had this issue since.  I think the issue started after tinkering around too much inside the emulator.